# Getting error while creating hive external table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

while creating external hive table getting below error hive (yatish)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE yatish_h1b_data_ak 
(    
     ID:INT,
     CASE_STATUS:VARCHAR,
     EMPLOYER_NAME:VARCHAR,
     SOC_NAME:VARCHAR,
     JOB_TITLE:VARCHAR,
     FULL_TIME_POSITION:VARCHAR,
     PREVAILING_WAGE:FLOAT,
     YEAR:INT,
     WORKSITE:VARCHAR,
     LONGITUDE:VARCHAR,
     LATITUDE:VARCHAR 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED              
FIELDS TERMINATED BY \073' LINE TERMINATED BY '\n'              
LOCATION user/seethayatish/yatish;
```

> NoViableAltException(9@[])
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.type(HiveParser.java:40648)           > at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.colType(HiveParser.java:40405)           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:40089)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:38213)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:6726)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:4122)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1786)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1152)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:211)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:171)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:447)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:330)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1233)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1274)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1170)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1160)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:217)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:169)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:380)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:740)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:685)         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)         at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148) FAILED: ParseException line 1:45 cannot recognize input near ':' 'INT' ',' in column type

Comment: You have wrongly written Creat table statement. There is no colon sign(:) between field name and its datatype. Just keep space between field name and its data type.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly written Creat table statement. There is no colon sign(:) between field name and its datatype. Just keep space between field name and its data type. Also there is no VARCHAR and FLOAT type supported in hive, instead of that use STRING and DOUBLE.

Below is correct statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE yatish_h1b_data_ak ( 

ID                   INT,
CASE_STATUS          STRING,
EMPLOYER_NAME        STRING,
SOC_NAME             STRING,
JOB_TITLE            STRING,
FULL_TIME_POSITION   STRING,
PREVAILING_WAGE      FLOAT,
YEAR                 INT,
WORKSITE             STRING,
LONGITUDE            STRING,
LATITUDE             STRING ) 

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED  

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\073' 

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 

LOCATION '/user/seethayatish/yatish';
```

Comment: FAILED: ParseException line 5:0 cannot recognize input near 'LINE' 'TERMINATED' 'BY' in serde properties specification